# redirection to wait until python script has completed its task in django

Tags: django, python-2.7, hive

I am running a python script  which runs hive. now i want to integrate it with django and want to redirect it to a different view after that hive querying is completed and till then wait for it to complete on the same view. How should I do it?

any help would be crucial

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use any task queue solution like Celery, Huey or RQ ([djangopackages](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/workers-queues-tasks/)).

1. Put task in the queue
2. Redirect user to the task page with `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">` in html head

Simple view example for task page:

```
def task_in_progress(request, task_in_queue_id):
    task = get_task_from_queue(task_in_queue_id)
    if task.is_comlete():
        HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('task_completed', args=(task_in_queue_id,)))
    return render(request, 'task_in_progress.html')
```

Comment: thanks for your response.but i am still not clear with how to use tasks and queues over here. if possible,please elaborate this solution

Comment: @user2345523 Did you read the [usage guide](https://github.com/ui/django-rq#usage)?

Comment: yes i do have.but that doesnt properly explain how to use rq in the django project. i have dont till modifying settings.py file (addition of rq_usage and imports), but adding my view function in queue is still not clear. Also , i only require a single task in queue and after its completion other scripts can work normally

Comment: ok so i am able to check whether the job is completed or not but ony at a certain point of point(i can add the sleep) but before running the process i wont know how much time it would take to complte the job.please help soon